# How do I make CodeRush work with both VS2012 and VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, coderush

I am trying to make CodeRush 15.1.4.0 (trial) work on both VS2012 and VS2013 on the same machine. It runs fine on VS2012 but on VS2013 only IntelliSense is working - the rest of the tools are gone.

On another machine with only VS2013 installed, CodeRush is working perfectly.

Does anybody else have this issue, or can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps run the installer again in repair mode?

In any case, I'd suggest reporting this to support@devexpress.com.

Support are very helpful and will follow up with you until your issue is resolved.

Comment: I've done repair, reinstall and it still doesn't appear in VS2013.